# JSON parse and stringify error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please can you help -- why does this JSON not work

the head of my page looks like this

```
<script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and my ajax looks like this

```
var p = { "myText": JSON.stringify(tableOBJ) };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default2AJAX.aspx",
    data: p,
    success: function (data) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    }
});
```

In firefox I get this error on the JSON

> Error: syntax error
>   Source File: /Scripts/json2.js
>   Line: 4
>   Source Code:
>   `<!DOCTYPE html>`

In IE 7 I get `JSON undefined`

in ie 8 i get

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error  json2.js, line 4 character 1

In ie 9 i get

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error  json2.js, line 4 character 1

How do I fix this? as I have added json2.js but it appear if the browser doesnt need it it throws an error?

Comment: its my javascript file with my ajax in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an error in the json2.js file you are using -- at least IE 8 & 9 agree that an error exists on line 4 of that file.

Comment: thanks you where correct it was my json2 file that had an error

Answer (score 3):

Change Scripts/json2.js to point to a real copy of json2.js. At the moment it is pointing to an HTML document (probably a 404 error page).

Answer (score 2):

I am betting that the file *"Scripts/JScript.js"* does not exist on your server and that the `Source Code: <!DOCTYPE html>` is a 404 error page.

Answer (score 2):

@Hello-Word & @Rocket Hazmat:

The file at github link is an html file. To solve the problem:

1. Download json2.js
2. Change the file extension to html
3. Open the file in a web browser
4. Scroll down the page, copy the javascript code portion, and save it to a new file as json2.js

BTW, thanks to Douglas for the json parser.  Makes my life much easier.